# DataGridView CellValidating returns empty string on new row

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview

My `DataGridView` is representing a MySQL table which you can edit. However, the first column needs to follow a strict pattern what i need to validate. I use the following code to do so :

```
Private Sub dg_Temp_CellValidating(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs) Handles dg_Temp.CellValidating
    Dim strActiveCell = dg_Temp(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex).Value.ToString
    If e.ColumnIndex = 0 Then
        If Regex.IsMatch(strActiveCell, "M[0-9]{3}[a-z]{1}[A-Z]{1}") = False Then
            e.Cancel = True
            MsgBox("Invalid material id structure." & Chr(13) & "Only the following syntax is legal: M000aA" &
                   Chr(13) & "Entered: " & strActiveCell)
        End If
    ElseIf strActiveCell = vbNullString Then
        dg_Temp(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex).Value = ""
    End If
End Sub
```

However, when editing existing rows, everything works fine. But when creating a new row , `dg_Temp(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex).Value.ToString` returns nothing. What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried using  `e.FormattedValue` instead of `g_Temp(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex).Value` ?

Comment: Thanks, thats excactly what I needed! Maybe post it as answer, so I can mark it. @AlexB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the event parameter `e.FormattedValue` to get the current value of the cell being validated.

`g_Temp(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex).Value` seems to be set not until after the `CellValidating` event.